# ¿como puedo convertir un endpoint que no devuelve nada a que devuelva algo? c# core.net 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

hola hoy quería saber como puedo hacer que mi endpoint el cual esta contruido asi :

***endpoint:***

```
[HttpGet("GetSignatureChecklist")]
        public async Task GetSignature([FromQuery] List<ChecklistSignature> filter)
        {
           await _processorSignatureCheckList.GetCheckListSignatureProcessor(filter);
           
        }
```

***processor:***

```
public async Task GetCheckListSignatureProcessor(List<ChecklistSignature> filter)
        {
           await _repository.ChecklistSignature(filter);
        }
```

***repository:***

```
public async Task GetChecklistSignature(List<ChecklistSignature> filter)
        {
            using (var db = Connection)
            {
             var data = await db.ExecuteAsync($@"select from CheckListsSignature", filter);
                
            }
        }
```

en el cual ninguno de ellos devuelve nada **¿como puedo implementar un return en este enpoint?**

agradeceria la ayuda ya que no cuento con muchos conocimentos en .net bonito dia

Comment: Define `que devuelva algo` por favor, porque tranquilamente puedes poner `return Ok();` en el `controller` y ya te está devolviendo algo: un `200 ok`. ¿Se entiende la idea?

Comment: @fredyfx claro que si pero cuando coloco return me salta error creo que es porque me hace falta configurar algo porque por el task ya devuelve el ok de por si pero por ejemplo la consulta sql que quiero que me devuelva unos datos devo de retornar eso pero no puedo porque me salta un error de no puedo retornar por el task

Comment: `return Ok(await _processorSignatureCheckList.GetCheckListSignatureProcessor(filter));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reemplaza:

```
public async Task GetSignature
```

Por:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSignature
```

Ahora le puedes agregar al controller:

```
return Ok(); // Y en teoría ya te está devolviendo ese "algo"
```

Comment: es muy buena solucion gracias pero tengo una duda como devuelvo la consulta que hago en repository

Comment: Vamos por partes, esa es otra pregunta. Crea una nueva y coloca más detalles para reproducir tu escenario y cosas que se requieran en la devolución de información de la bd.